# Why Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap myBitmap) update myBitmap

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap

I have no problems , but I want to understand one thing for personal experience

```
var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap myBitmap)
...
graphics.DrawImage(Image image, Rectangle destRect, int srcX, int srcY, int srcWidth, int srcHeight, GraphicsUnit srcUnit, ImageAttributes imageAttr)
```

So , the question is : why after I called the function `myBitmap` was updated but `FromImage()` dont get `ref` or `out` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Bitmap` class is an reference type, so an reference (pointer) get passed by value.

Here's an explanation what C# is really doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9717120/4783560