# How to connect two classes together

Tags: c#, class, properties, reference

I am making a gallery tool that lets you browse and edit objects. I have a 'Library' class that manages the fetching and displaying of the gallery list. I also have an 'ActiveItem' asset that loads all the information of the selected object and deals with modifying it.

Now, there's some information that is stored in the 'library' class (for example the filepath) that I want to use in my activeitem.

I'm a bit confused as to how I can set this up efficiently.

I thought about embedding the activeitem class in the library class, but it gets a bit annoying to have to access all functions and properties of the activeitem through the library class (so instead of writing activeitem.Load() I would have to write lib.activeitem.Load() ). Activeitem already goes 4 levels deep and it's getting a bit much.

Are there other ways of setting this up? Can I store a reference of the library class instance inside the activeitem class, so that the activeitem class can fetch a property of the library instance?

Edit: added some code snippets

This are the class definitions:

```
class Library
{
    ...
    public string LibDirectory;
    ...
}


class ActiveAsset
{
    ...

    public SaveAsset()
    {
        //this method needs to know the LibDirectory property of the libraryclass
    }
 }
```

On initiating my winform, I initiate both classes:

```
Library lib = new Library();
ActiveAsset activeAsset = new ActiveAsset();
```

Comment: Yes, you can have a reference to library in your other class. `var lib = new Library();` or something like that. You haven't shown any code. If your class is static it is a different story.

Comment: Please share some code, that might help get you a better answer.  What instantiates ActiveItem?  It sounds like Library is maintaining a list of items and once one is selected it becomes the active item?

Comment: @Crowcoder wouldn't that instantiate a new class instead of holding a reference to an (already instantiated) instance of the Library class?

Comment: @Schiette yes but without any context I can't tell you how to reference an already instantiated instance.

Comment: @Frank Your description is correct. Like Di.dev suggested, I could build a wrapper class, but I'm wondering whether it's good practice to keep nested classes deeper and deeper. I'm already 5 classes deep, I'm wondering whether keep adding 'levels' is
(1) going to affect performance?
(2) isn't it going to become very unpractical to access certain properties because you have to go X levels deep? Class1.class2.class3.class4.class5.GetPropertyX() ?

I'm new to setting up a larger program structure and I feel I'm missing something here.

Comment: Added code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the concerns in the question comments, if you want ActiveAsset to be able to read information from Library you could change ActiveAsset's constructor to take in Library and store it internally as a private var.

```
class ActiveAsset
{
   private Library _lib   

   public ActiveAsset(Library lib) {
     this._lib = lib
   }

    public SaveAsset()
    {
        // reach lib instance from here
        this._lib.LibDirectory
        //this method needs to know the LibDirectory property of the libraryclass
    }
 }
```

If you are worried about design and coupling you could make in interface for Library and then make the constructor use that instead of the Library class

```
 interface ILibrary {
    string LibDir { get; set; }
 }
 
 class Library : ILibrary {

 }

 class ActiveAsset
{
   private ILibrary _lib   

   public ActiveAsset(Library lib) {
     this._lib = lib
   }

    public SaveAsset()
    {
        // reach lib instance from here
        this._lib.LibDirectory
        //this method needs to know the LibDirectory property of the libraryclass
    }
 }
```

As for performance and creating deep levels of nested classes I don't think you will have to worry so much about it, chances are you will hit data save/retrieve performance issues before anything like too many classes.  That kind of performance design is only really important when you try to make you code work on small platforms where memory is limited like rasberryPi and such.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. A question regarding your first codesnippet: (1) could it be you meant to write public ActiveAsset(Library lib) instead of public ActiveAsset(lib Library) ?  Or am I missing something? (2) Isn't this copying the Library instance into the class? If the original library LibDirectory would change, it wouldn't automatically update in the copied version that saved in the ActiveAsset? Am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I got the variable typing position messed up, it should be type then name, I will updated the answer.  For question 2:  Yes we are copying the variable and keeping it in the ActiveAsset but since the type is Library which is a class it will copy by reference meaning you get a pointer to the same instance out side the class.   Check out this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9717057/c-sharp-passing-arguments-by-default-is-byref-instead-of-byval) that dicusses by ref/by val in C#

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a wrapper class which holds both the Library and the ActiveItem instances. Thus you can have more generalised methods like:

- GetAllItems() - gets all items from the library
- ActivateItem(Item item) - activates the item provided (stores the given item to a variable in the wrapper class)

etc. Think of that wrapper class as the manager of your application. You would only like to work with that manager regardless of what's beneath it.